# Javascript function only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, umbraco

I have a forum that has a "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" button. When you hit it once, it changes but then doesn't switch back again until the page is refreshed.

http://jsfiddle.net/7QPyL/

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

// Subscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
$(".notsubscribedtotopic").click(function () {
    var topicid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).html('Unsubscribe From Topic');
    $(this).removeClass('notsubscribedtotopic').addClass('subscribedtotopic');
    $(this).slideDown();
    $.get("/base/Solution/SubScribeToTopic/" + topicid + ".aspx",
    function (data) {
        var result = $('value', data).text();
    });
    return false;
});

// UnSubscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
$(".subscribedtotopic").click(function () {
    var topicid = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(this).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).html('Subscribe To Topic');
    $(this).removeClass('subscribedtotopic').addClass('notsubscribedtotopic');
    $(this).slideDown();
    $.get("/base/Solution/UnSubScribeToTopic/" + topicid + ".aspx",
    function (data) {
        var result = $('value', data).text();
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle with the HTML as well.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the   $(this).removeClass('notsubscribedtotopic').addClass('subscribedtotopic'); line as you are binding event on dom having the same class which you are removing here

Comment: Sorry - Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7QPyL/

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because the class is not there when you add the event handler, so it can not find the element.

`$(".notsubscribedtotopic")` and `$(".subscribedtotopic")` do not magically select new elements as they are added to the page.

You should write one function and just toggle the state.

```
$(".subscribe").click(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    var isSubscribbed = link.hasClass("subscribedtotopic");
    link.toggleClass("subscribedtotopic notsubscribedtotopic");
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up your code to be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Subscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    function subscribetotopic() {
        var topicid = $(this).attr('rel');
        $(this).slideUp('fast');
        $(this).html('Unsubscribe From Topic');
        $(this).removeClass('notsubscribedtotopic').addClass('subscribedtotopic');
        $(this).slideDown();
        $.get("/base/Solution/SubScribeToTopic/" + topicid + ".aspx",
            function (data) {
                var result = $('value', data).text();
            });
        return false;
    }

    // UnSubscribe to topic subscribedtotopic
    function unsubscribetotopic() {
        var topicid = $(this).attr('rel');
        $(this).slideUp('fast');
        $(this).html('Subscribe To Topic');
        $(this).removeClass('subscribedtotopic').addClass('notsubscribedtotopic');
        $(this).slideDown();
        $.get("/base/Solution/UnSubScribeToTopic/" + topicid + ".aspx",
            function (data) {
                var result = $('value', data).text();
            });
        return false;
    }
});
```

And then make a simple onclick call in your HTML element, like so:

```
<button onclick="subscribetotopic()">Subscribe</button>
```

If you'd prefer to keep your code the way it is, then clarify which element you want to have active.
Example (simply set a div w/ id mymainelement and button w/ id subscribebutton):

```
$(#mymainelement .subscribebutton).click(function() { ... });
```

If you'd prefer to toggle the button instead of having two separate elements, check out @epsacarello's answer.